# Read File byte after byte in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, binaryfiles

I am looking for a way to read a big binary file using VBScript (big - 1 GB). I can't read it directly with `ReadAll` function because the file is too big, so I am looking for a way to read it in a loop, like in C. So I want to read X bytes, process them (I don't need the full file to do my stuff), then read next 10 and over again.

The problem is that I can't find a way to do that, I know how to start reading from offset, but can't find a way to read X bytes, there are only `ReadAll` and `ReadLine` functions.

Is there a way to read X bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/dhyx75w2%28v%3dvs.84%29):

> ## Read Method
>
> Reads a specified number of characters from a TextStream file and returns the resulting string.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> object.Read(characters)
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> - *object*
>     Required. Always the name of a TextStream object.
> - *characters*
>     Required. Number of characters you want to read from the file.

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.file"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f   = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    buf = f.Read(10)
    '...
Loop

f.Close
```

Note, however, that the `Read()` method doesn't read bytes per se, but characters. Which is roughly the same as long as you open the file in ANSI mode (the default).

Comment: So, I can use it only if I have a textual file? If its a binary file I have a problem?

Comment: Please re-read my answer, specifically the last paragraph. (TL;DR: no)